# make checkbox automatically checked within table PHP

Tags: php, checkbox, checked

I am new to PHP and I have problem. I have a table with check boxes. I need to add if statement inside the check box.

```
  echo "<div class='table1'>
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Module code</td>
<td>Module Title</td>
<td>Option</td>
</tr>";
echo "<form action='confirmsubmission.php' method='post'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='check[]'  
value='".$row['module_id']."' />" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['module_id'] .  "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['module_title'] . "<a href=# content='".$row['description']."'
class='tooltip'><span title='Module Description'><img src='images/i.png'/></span>
</a>". "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['module_choice'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table></div>";
```

Below is a If statement I need to add after value='".$row['module_id']."'

```
 if($row['module_choice']=='Mandatory'){ echo "checked=\"true\""; }
```

Comment: checked='checked' i don't think html uses escape characters, so \" inside your string probably won't work

Comment: @JeffHawthorne `checked="checked"` is correct, but the escaping is there for PHP, not HTML.

Comment: @Colin Morelli it's inside an echo string though, will php even see it?

Comment: @JeffHawthorne If it were `echo "checked="true"";`, PHP would complain about a parse error because of the quotes. Using `echo "checked=\"true\""` tells PHP that the quotes should be echoed as well, and shouldn't be interpreted as the end of the string.

Comment: gotcha, i usually just mix the quote types for simplicity because php doesn't make a huge distinction between single and double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a mouthful, but try:

```
...    
echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='".$row['module_id']."'".($row['module_choice']=='Mandatory' ? 'checked="true"' : "")." />" . "</td>";
...
```

Comment: Read thanks so much...that worked. I've spend almost two days to fix it.....Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: @dimitiy - In that case a click on the tick would do nicely, please!

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'll advise you to use a templating system (Smarty, etc.), you can do the following code:

```php
echo "<div class='table1'>
<form action='confirmsubmission.php' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Module code</td>
<td>Module Title</td>
<td>Option</td>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='check[]'  
value='".$row['module_id']."'";
if($row['module_choice']=='Mandatory'){ 
    echo " checked='checked' "; 
}
echo "/>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['module_id'] .  "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['module_title'] . "<a href=# content='".$row['description']."'
class='tooltip'><span title='Module Description'><img src='images/i.png'/></span>
</a>". "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['module_choice'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table></form></div>";
```